# Why does a not found error occur in ssh in GitHub Actions?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, github-actions, synology

github action ssh img
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOuqn.png)

First of all, `docker --version` can be done normally when connected via ssh from a local PC.
When using [`ssh-action`](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action), docker is not found occurs.
and `whoami` command works normally in GitHub Actions.

The server I am using is using the latest version of Synology, which seems to be Ubuntu-based.

I'm curious what causes this problem.

Synology log is as follows.

```
User [*****] from [**.**.***.*] logged in successfully via [SSH].
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIgH0.png)